# Is there a way I can emulate an Xbox 360 controller on the PC?

Tags: pc, controllers

On my PC, I have a non Xbox controller which has exactly the same button scheme as Xbox controllers. However, I cannot play a lot of Windows Live games (Fallout 3, Batman: Arkham Asylum) using it though because it's not a genuine Xbox controller.

Is there some sort of program that will allow me to emulate my controller so that it'll be recognized as an Xbox controller for the PC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [Xbox 360 Controller Emulator](http://www.tocaedit.com/IB/index.php?automodule=downloads&showfile=54).

There's a handy [guide](http://www.fragtheplanet.com/808/emulate-an-xbox-360-controller/), written for an older version, but could still be relevant to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I haven't tried this myself.

You can try a profiler like [this one](http://pinnaclegameprofiler.com/) (paid) or [this one](http://www.racketboy.com/retro/2007/05/xpadder-use-your-pc-gamepad-instead-of-keyboard.html) (free). I'm sure there are others, too. It looks like they work by setting up a mapping between your controller and the keyboard/mouse, so you should be able to set your controller up without relying on the game recognizing it.